# Проблемы с sql запросом. Ошибка в синтаксисе

Tags: sql, запрос

Вопрос следующий. Есть запрос:

```
SELECT [Фамилия]
  ,[Сумма_зароботной_платы]
  ,[Код_разряда]
  ,[Код_цеха]
  ,[Код_профессии]
  ,[Код_сотрудника]
  FROM [Карточка_сотрудника] 
WHERE (NOT Right([Фамилия],2)='ов');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А надо, что не бы выводило там, где в конце фамилии ов. 
Подскажите в чем ошибка.

Comment: `Right([Фамилия],2) != 'ов'` ?  А ошибка в синтаксисе обычно показывает где именно ... Дело в том, что ваш NOT в принципе то же дложен работать. так что надо еще посмотреть что за ошибку точно он выдает

Comment: Ошибку по факту не пишет. А если убрать not вовсе, то не выводит ничего совсем. Так как у вас получается идентично моему запросу.

Comment: Ошибка в том, что у меня тип данных выбран char(25). Скорее среда остальные символы пробелами заполнила автоматически.

Comment: если там и пробелы то это все равно не даст синтаксической ошибки. Да, у меня идентично вашему запросу все отлично работает. А пробелы можно TRIM() убрать